# Dynamically excluude items from queryset django

Tags: django

I am looking to dynamically exclude items from a queryset based on they're foreign key content but my call to exclude seems to have no effect.

```
address_list = Address.objects.all()
for address in address_list:
            if not address.vendor_set.all():
               address_list.exclude(id=address.id)
```

If the vendor set returns none i want to remove that item but i seem to be missing something. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop you've written loops through the queryset then generates a new queryset every time the `if` statement runs, which it doesn't assign to any variable so is immediately garbage collected.

You can achieve what I think you want with a list comprehension:

```
address_list = Address.objects.all()
filtered_list = [x for x in address_list if x.vendor_set.all()]
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Address.objects.exclude(vendor_set__isnull=True)
```

This will return every Address having a non-null `vendor_set`. When you query as a parameter, you can use:

```
vendor_set__isnull=True|False
```

to get whether the RelatedManager has any objects for it (this assertion is only meaningful at queryset level - it **does not** mean the same as `anAddress.vendor_set is None` because this in-model assertion will be always false). You can also query:

```
vendor_set__name="foo"
```

if Vendor has a `name` attributo, to test if **at least one vendor in vendor_set** has a name with "foo". But the first case can help you to test if the item has no vendors at all, and so excluding it.

If I misunderstood, and you actually want to keep only such items (i.e. the inverse case) then you can:

```
Address.objects.exclude(vendor_set__isnull=False)
```

or

```
Address.objects.filter(vendor_set__isnull=True)
```

**Edit** for future readers: According to comments by @sirFunkenstine (the OP), this solution works but requires an explicit `related_name=` in the foreign key (i.e. `related_name="vendor_set"` in this case), or will throw an error.

Comment: Althought I answered, I use to forget this every time.

Comment: The above answers initially threw up an error's saying object does not contain field 'vendor_set' and listed vendor customer and other fields. I added the following to my address model address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name="vendor_set") and now the above solutions work perfectly. Thanks guys!

Comment: I will edit to add your comment. My experience was always specifying the `related_name`. Perhaps a bug in django?

Answer (score -1):

You can exclude null datasets from django queryset directly like this 
    `Address.objects.filter((vendor_set.all())__isnull=False)`

or as well well you can used exclude like this
    `Address.objects.exclude((vendor_set.all())__isnull=True)`

The magic function should work

Comment: That's not even valid python syntax!